# Manipulating two 'backgrounds' of the same class

Tags: javascript, css

Example: I want to manipulate both of these backgrounds with javascript. How would I target each individual one? Is there a better way to do this?

```
.mainDiv {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #673ab7, #512da8); 
background: linear-gradient(to right, #673ab7, #512da8); 
}
```

Comment: Looking at [this](https://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient) you can probably ditch the prefix one.

Comment: Better way than what? What manipulation are you looking to make on them?

Comment: I think you are doing a misunderstanding. Theses both background are the same. `-webkit-` is a vendor prefix for browsers based on webkit technology. The second is the standard way to declare `linear-gradient` accept for all modern browsers.

Comment: @Alohci If I wanted to change the gradient color with JS to a gradient with 3 or 4 colors, I'm not sure how to access both of the same background to do so.

Comment: @PabloDarde Really? I am new to this.. I had figured it was good to include a webkit for certain things for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Yes, it is a good practice to increase browser compatibility. You can also include `-moz-linear-gradient` to reach old versions of firefox.